# The form was not loaded due to an error. 401 403 unauthorized

Tags: security, sitecore-forms

Using custom roles setup to lockdown access. Gave access rights to the Forms folder and the app menu for the launchpad. However I receive the error on the GUI after clicking one of the forms to open it:

> The form was not loaded due to an error.

F12 dev tools reveals 401/403 unauthorized for some api call (`formbuilder/load`), and also another error on the dev tools on the main Forms page (`getFormDetails` api call).

Answer (score 1):

If you are restricting access, some functionality requires specific roles. In this case for Forms, the role "Forms Editor" needs to be assigned to either the role or user.

Reference: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/setting_up_and_configuring/the_security_roles_in_sitecore_forms