# Creating new Form error `The Form was not loaded due to an error`

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am having some trouble creating a new Sitecore Form. I am able to launch the Forms app. But when I click the blue `Create` button and select `Blank form`, the page loads for a second and then displays an error: `The form was not loaded due to an error.`

[image]

I did some snooping, and found that around the time the page switches to the error mode there is a 404 error being returned for an API request to `http://mydomain.localhost/formbuilder/load?id=&sc_formmode=new&sc_formlang=&_=1565192173806`. Tracked that down to a call from a Javascript file `http://mydomain.localhost/-/speak/v1/components/FormDesignBoard.js`.

[image]

Any ideas what could be causing this error? I found [this other question that seems similar](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13963/the-form-was-not-loaded-due-to-an-error-401-403-unauthorized), though their error reports a 401/403 while my AJAX request definitely returns a 404. I tried their recommendation to add the `sitecore/Forms Editor` role to my Administrator user, but no luck. Still get the same 404 result. Even tried logging out/in again and rebooting my local server after altering my user roles.

As referenced [in my previous question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20246/exception-when-opening-the-sitecore-9-forms-application), I am running Sitecore 9.0.1 r171219 that we upgraded from Sitecore 8.1.0 r160302. It is quite possible that something did not get upgraded properly, but I am at a loss as to where to look.

I tried swapping my Core database for the stock Core Sitecore database provided in the 9.0.1 release, but still received the same error.

I've also gone through the filesystem and compared my site structure to the stock Sitecore file structure. There were differences, but they were ones that I expected to see; nothing jumped out at me as being related to Forms functionality.

Edit: 
Log files show nothing of interest, sadly.

Have now also commented out a couple `httpRequestBegin` pipelines to see if they were the cause. No luck -- still same 404 error.

Anyone have any ideas on other things to look at?

Comment: Have you checked your log files for errors related to this?

Comment: do you have any rewrite module or a custom processor in the `httpBeginRequest` pipeline? check your custom implementation especially which are related to requests.

Comment: @RichardSeal I did check the logs! Nothing interesting there, unfortunately.

Comment: @TamásTárnok Perhaps something to consider there. We are using the Sitecore.MultisiteHttpModule.NotFound.NotFoundHandler.

Comment: @BU0 try to disable this module and see if this the root of the issue.

Comment: @TamásTárnok Good idea, but no luck there either unfortunately. I removed the .config file completely, but still receive the same 404 error on that /formbuilder/load endpoint.

Comment: `Edit: Log files show nothing of interest, sadly.`. I don't believe that. At the exact moment of that error appearing on your screen, there would be an exception in your log. Post it. You're here because you're overlooking the solution.

Comment: @MarkCassidy I could definitely be overlooking something; there are quite a few places to look, and I definitely don't know them all! Where would you suggest looking? 

I have my default log levels set to INFO. There are certainly things being logged, but I'm not seeing anything that appears to directly relate to this 404 request. I can hit the requested URL manually and get the same 404 result, so it is pretty easy to test. I've done this multiple times. Log file timestamps and sizes do not change after the request finishes.

Comment: @BU0 try to disable your custom configs one-by-one to detect where the problem could be, I am sure it is caused by a custom processor or a `rewrite` rule in the `Web.config`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was caused by a poor Sitecore 9.0.1 upgrade. I ended up installing a fresh 9.0.1 site, and then migrating my content & code over to that. Forms area is working now.